# Nested dynamic form fields in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a form with dynamic input fields using react-bootstrap forms.

[image]

The above is the basic layout. When '+Add More' is clicked, a set of tier fields(min, max, metric, amount) will be shown. When '+Add Region' is clicked, a set of geography and tier will be shown.

```
//to add a tier
addTClick = () => {
       this.setState({ tieredInputs: this.state.tieredInputs.concat([{ min: 0, max: 0, metric: 'aDAU', amount: 0 }])});
}

//to remove a tier     
removeTClick = (idx) => {
     this.setState({ tieredInputs: this.state.tieredInputs.filter((s, sidx) => idx !== sidx)});
}

//to add region and tier
addFTClick = () => {
   const new_tiered_inputs = [{ min: 0, max: 0, metric: 'aDAU', amt: 0 }];
   this.setState({ 
       fullTier: this.state.fullTier.concat([{ region: [], new_tiered_inputs }])
   });
}

{this.state.fullTier.map((tier, i) => (
   <div key={i} class="fulltier">
      <Form.Group className="full-width">
         <Form.Label className="main-label">Geography</Form.Label>
          <DropDownRegions data={regionsData} onChange={this.onChange}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="full-width">
          <Form.Label className="main-label">Tiers</Form.Label>
             {this.state.tieredInputs.map((tieredInput, idx) => (
                <div key={idx} className="tier">
                   <Form.Row>
                      <Col sm={12} md={2} lg={2}>
                          <Form.Group className="">
                               <Form.Label>Min</Form.Label>
                               <Form.Control
                                            placeholder="0"
                                            aria-lable="min range"
                                            name="min_range"
                                            required
                                            ref="min_range"
                                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}></Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={12} md={2} lg={2}>
                                    <Form.Group className="">
                                        <Form.Label>Max</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            placeholder="0"
                                            aria-lable="max range"
                                            name="max_range"
                                            required
                                            ref="max_range"
                                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}></Form.Control>
                                    </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={12} md={3} lg={3}>
                                    <Form.Group className="">
                                        <Form.Label>Metric</Form.Label>
                                        <Select 
                                            value={metricSelectedOption.label}
                                            name="tiered_metric"
                                            onChange={(e) => this.handleMetricChange(e)}
                                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}
                                            options={this.state.metricList}></Select>
                                    </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={12} md={3} lg={3}>
                                    <Form.Label>Amount</Form.Label>
                                    <InputGroup className="mmb-3 fw">
                                        <Form.Control
                                            placeholder="0.00"
                                            aria-label="tiered amount"
                                            aria-describedby="tiered-amt-addon2"
                                            name="tiered_amount"
                                            pattern="^\d*\.\d{1,18}$"
                                            required
                                            ref="tiered_amt"
                                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}
                                        />
                                        <InputGroup.Append>
                                            <InputGroup.Text id="tiered-amt-addon2">USD</InputGroup.Text>
                                        </InputGroup.Append>
                                    </InputGroup>
                             </Col>
                             <Col>
                                    <Button className="dangerBtn mtop" onClick={this.removeTClick.bind(this, idx)}>
                                        <FaTrashAlt />
                                    </Button>
                             </Col>
                        </Form.Row>
                    </div>
               ))}
               <Form.Row>
                   <Button style={{marginTop: '-20px'}} variant="link" className="addMoreBtn" onClick={this.addTClick.bind(this)}>+Add More</Button>
               </Form.Row>
       </Form.Group>
   </div>
))}
<Form.Row>
    <Button className="addMoreBtn" onClick={this.addFTClick.bind(this)}>+Add Region</Button>
</Form.Row>
```

The above is my code for adding the fields but after adding a new region, when '+Add More' is clicked, the new set of tier fields are added in both the groups (likewise on delete, it gets removed from both).

How can I make the '+Add More' work only for the group in which it was clicked?(similarly for delete).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you kindly add your implementation for the onChange events for the fields as well as the "remove region and tier" ?
This will really help me in the issues I am trying to solve similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to take a guess at the rest of your code, but the issue is trying to store the `fullTier` and `tieredInputs` in different state values. You can store everything in the `fullTier` state values and modify accordingly using the `i` and `idx` values. Here is a working example, with what I was guessing the rest of your code to be: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-water-scig2?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Button, Container, Col, Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tiers: [
        {
          region: [],
          tieredInputs: [{ min: 0, max: 0, metric: "aDAU", amt: 0 }]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  //to add a tier
  addTClick = (i) => {
    const tiers = [...this.state.tiers];
    tiers[i].tieredInputs.push({ min: 0, max: 0, metric: "aDAU", amount: 0 });
    this.setState({ tiers });
  };

  //to remove a tier
  removeTClick = (i, idx) => {
    const tiers = [...this.state.tiers];
    tiers[i].tieredInputs.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ tiers });
  };

  //to add region and tier
  addFTClick = () => {
    const tiers = [...this.state.tiers];
    tiers.push({
      region: [],
      tieredInputs: [{ min: 0, max: 0, metric: "aDAU", amt: 0 }]
    });
    this.setState({ tiers });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.state.tiers.map((tier, i) => (
          <Form.Row key={i}>
            <div>
              <Form.Group className="full-width">
                <Form.Label className="main-label">Geography</Form.Label>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="full-width">
                <Form.Label className="main-label">Tiers</Form.Label>
                {tier.tieredInputs.map((tieredInput, idx) => (
                  <div key={idx} className="tier">
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Col sm={12} md={2} lg={2}>
                        <Form.Group className="">
                          <Form.Label>Min</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control
                            placeholder="0"
                            aria-label="min range"
                            name="min_range"
                            required
                            ref="min_range"
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}
                          ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                      </Col>
                      <Col sm={12} md={2} lg={2}>
                        <Form.Group className="">
                          <Form.Label>Max</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control
                            placeholder="0"
                            aria-label="max range"
                            name="max_range"
                            required
                            ref="max_range"
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}
                          ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
                      </Col>
                      <Col sm={12} md={3} lg={3}>
                        <Form.Label>Amount</Form.Label>
                        <InputGroup className="mmb-3 fw">
                          <Form.Control
                            placeholder="0.00"
                            aria-label="tiered amount"
                            aria-describedby="tiered-amt-addon2"
                            name="tiered_amount"
                            pattern="^\d*\.\d{1,18}$"
                            required
                            ref="tiered_amt"
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleTChange(e)}
                            onClick={(e) => this.setSelectedIndex(idx)}
                          />
                          <InputGroup.Append>
                            <InputGroup.Text id="tiered-amt-addon2">
                              USD
                            </InputGroup.Text>
                          </InputGroup.Append>
                        </InputGroup>
                      </Col>
                      <Col
                        style={{
                          display: "flex",
                          alignItems: "center",
                          marginTop: 16
                        }}
                      >
                        <Button
                          variant="danger"
                          onClick={this.removeTClick.bind(this, i, idx)}
                        >
                          <FaTrashAlt />
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                  </div>
                ))}
                <Form.Row>
                  <Button
                    variant="link"
                    className="addMoreBtn"
                    onClick={this.addTClick.bind(this, i)}
                  >
                    +Add More
                  </Button>
                </Form.Row>
              </Form.Group>
            </div>
          </Form.Row>
        ))}
        <Form.Row>
          <Button className="addMoreBtn" onClick={this.addFTClick.bind(this)}>
            +Add Region
          </Button>
        </Form.Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked! I understand a bit more on how nested display works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly the problem I am trying to solve. Can you also include how [region and tier] can be removed at the same time and how to handle onChange event correctly for each of the fields ?